# Json Internal server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, internal-server-error

Hi i followed the following post in code project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu to create http handler to call web methods in asmx files using Json script. I'm getting Inter server error which is thrown by the error caught in the json script.

My code is as follows:

### ASMX

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CurrentHistoryfunctions : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {



        [WebMethod]
       [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static List<RefEmployee> GetEmployeeSummaryCurrent(string empNo)
        {
            EmployeeRepository empsumcurr = new EmployeeRepository();
            eturn empsumcurr.EmployeeSummaryCurrent(empNo);
        }
}
```

### Json script:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "Services/CurrentHistoryfunctions.asmx/GetEmployeeSummaryCurrent",
                data: JSON.stringify(emp),
                success: function (resp) {
                    var acc = []
                    if (resp.d[0] != null) {
                        $.each(resp.d[0], function (index, value) {
                            acc.push(index + ': ' + value);
                        });

                        $('#CurInfo').empty();
                        $('#CurInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'Employee Name: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPName + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Hire Date: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPHRDate + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Employee Status: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPSTUS + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Address: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPADDR1 + resp.d[0].EMPADDR2 + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'City: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPCity + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'State: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPState + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Zip: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPZip + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'AU: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].EMPAUCode + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Position: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].Position + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Marital Status: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].Marital_Status + '</p>' + '<p><b>' + 'Gender: ' + '</b>' + resp.d[0].Gender + '</p>');
                    }
                    else {

                        $('#CurInfo').empty();
                        $('#CurInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'No Current Data of Employee is Found' + '</b></p>');

                    }


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('TextStatus:' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                }
            })
```

Help me to solve this internal error problem.

Comment: Can you supply the error message from the server?

Comment: Are you using entity framework for your model classes? If so and you're not disabling proxy creation or lazy loading then when the language tries to serialize the objects it'll also attempt to lazy load properties and by that time the context is probably disposed.

Comment: The alert in error throws error.

Comment: @BoredBlazer: How to disable lazy load properties and proxy creation?

Comment: Is `eturn` inside of `GetEmployeeSummaryCurrent` a typo on SO or is it in the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to disable lazy loading and proxy creation in response to my question I'll go ahead and assume you're using entity framework. This only applies if you're using entity framework.

You really need to just disable proxy creation. This ensures lazy loading will not occur during serialization and give an internal server error. You can do this by accessing your context object after it is created, accessing its Configuration property, and then setting the Configuration property's ProxyCreationEnabled value to false. You must shut it off before you retrieve any of the objects to be serialized. In this case before you ever retrieve a RefEmployee object in the repository method you need to have proxy creation turned off. Make sure you turn it back on after you finish retrieving the objects for serialization unless you're sure you won't need proxies for the rest of that context's lifetime.

You might also want to read up on entity framework proxies and lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing static for my methods. Web service doesn't allow methods to be declared as static that is why my code didn't work but after removing static declaration it started working well.